Graphics problems with Ubuntu 24.04
I've had loads of problems since upgrading to 24.04. I originally upgraded my previous versions but then my PC started to get lots of snow crashes. So, I did a completely clean install on 24.04. There is still the no-thumbnail bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/2054183) - I tried switching on the "proposed" flag and looking for a new version off apparmor but there didn't seem to be one.
That's not my major issue at the moment though. I've now got a significant graphics problem - see below.

My graphics card is an Nvidia GeForce GT 710.
I've also gained printer issues and various other things. I love Ubuntu and have been using it for over a decade but 24.04 feels like it's been released with a lot of bugs.
Any help very much appreciated.
Thanks.

same here. upgraded from 23.x to 24.04 with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 770

update: this appears to have been fixed - I got an update bundle, rebooted and looks good again

Indeed! On the upside suddenly this issue looks completely fixed. On the downside it's made me realise I have no idea how to find out what updates have automatically been added to my PC. Info on major releases is easy to find - patches, not so much!

Try adding to /etc/environment the line:
GSK_RENDERER=gl

And then restart (or execute sudo systemctl restart gdm.service).
If that doesn't help, try adding one more line to the same file:
GDK_DEBUG=gl-prefer-gl

This has helped a lot of people to solve a lot of similar issues:

Ubuntu 24.04 screen glitches on gnome apps after install
24.04 LTS Texts don't appear until hover
Missing text in dialog windows

For further info and/or discussion see:

https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/1bnjx22/gnome_apps_do_not_show_text_unless_fullscreen/
https://www.phoronix.com/news/GTK-4.15-Vulkan-Default
https://blog.gtk.org/2024/01/28/new-renderers-for-gtk/


Thanks - looks like the patch yesterday solved this for a bunch of people including me,
